# How can I handle connection loss to RDS in Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a lambda function that connects to RDS.  I lose the connection to the database about once per day and have to wait for the lambda function to restart before any database queries work again.

How do I resolve this issue? Can I restart the lambda function each time I get a database error?

This is the initial connection error:

```
{
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
"code": "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST",
"fatal": true,
"stack": [
    "Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
    "    at Protocol.end (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)",
    "    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)",
    "    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)",
    "    at Socket.emit (events.js:322:22)",
    "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)",
    "    --------------------",
    "    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)",
    "    at Connection.query (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:200:25)",
    "    at /var/task/index.js:203:16",
    "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
    "    at executeSQL (/var/task/index.js:202:10)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:250:22)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
]
```

}

This is the error I get after the initial connection loss:

```
Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error
```

Here is a subset of my lambda function code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : process.env.ENDPOINT,
  user     : process.env.USERNAME,
  password : process.env.PASSWORD
});

console.log('connection: ', connection);

let dbInit = false;

async function conditionallyCreateDB(connection) {
  await executeSQL(connection, 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' + process.env.DBNAME);
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    connection.changeUser({ database: process.env.DBNAME }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      return resolve(data)
    } )
  })
}
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('Received event', JSON.stringify(event, null, 3));

  if (!dbInit) {
    await conditionallyCreateDB(connection);
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple solution is just to open and close the connection with each call to your function, instead of connecting once at initialization.

Comment: by putting the `mysql.createConnection` call within the handler?

Comment: yeah, I would test with that